# How can one confidently choose a p and q for a beta distribution?

Tags: distributions, beta-distribution

Is there a methodology or R tool that allows you to best attribute a p and q value for a Beta distribution? I am currently building a simulation that involves stochastic processes, and from the little empirical data I was able to obtain (30 data points) I developed a Cullen and Frey graph with bootstrapping to understand better what distribution my data follows, in this case, Beta. However, I have to also provide a p (lower shape parameter > 0), and a q (upper shape parameter > 0) for the distribution. I understand what they do however, I would like to know if there is a standard process to help one identify or estimate these parameters better.

Comment: What is the context? Do you have data and want to estimate the parameters? Something else? You need to tell us!

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Parameter_estimation

Comment: Is the question *"how do I fit a beta distribution to a set of empirical values?"*.

Comment: The use of 'better' is not very clear. Better than what? What are you currently using and what aspects do you consider/desire to make something better?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus yes, I believe that is the correct way to phrase the question. And when it comes to "better",, I just mean in the most optimal way. Excuse me.

Comment: What is optimal to you might be less optimal for another person. Christian shows a link with different methods to estimate the parameters and that is just a start. Context is needed in order to answe the question more specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to perform parameter estimation. This [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_theory#Estimators) page mentions a dozen of different types or related concepts:

> Commonly used estimators (estimation methods) and topics related to them include:
>
> - Maximum likelihood estimators
> - Bayes estimators
> - Method of moments estimators
> - Cramér–Rao bound
> - Least squares
> - Minimum mean squared error (MMSE), also known as Bayes least squared error (BLSE)
> - Maximum a posteriori (MAP)
> - Minimum variance unbiased estimator (MVUE)
> - Nonlinear system identification
> - Best linear unbiased estimator (BLUE)
> - Unbiased estimators — see estimator bias.
> - Particle filter
> - Markov chain Monte Carlo (MCMC)
> - Kalman filter, and its various derivatives
> - Wiener filter

As Christian Henning mentioned in the comments the beta distribution has [some simple solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Parameter_estimation) for a few of those methods.

---

This shows that there are a lot of various ways to estimate the parameters. These have all different advantages and disadvantages. Whichever is the 'most optimal way' will depend on the context.

This is not a standard straightforward filling in a function in R-code as if it is some oracle that gives you an answer to any dataset. You have to *think* yourselves as well about what you want the function/algorithm (the "oracle") to do for you.